# How to set which monitor the menu bar appears on?

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, menu

I'm running on a tiny netbook attached to a 22" monitor. When I'm using it without the monitor it makes sense to have the menu bar on the laptop monitor but when I have the big monitor plugged in I want the menu bar on the big monitor. How can I set it up this way?

Answer (score 2):

Set gnome-panel to the first (laptop) monitor type

```
   gconftool-2 --set "/apps/panel/toplevels/top_panel_screen0/monitor" --type integer "0"
```

For the second (external) monitor use

```
   gconftool-2 --set "/apps/panel/toplevels/top_panel_screen0/monitor" --type integer "1"
```

If you use awn instead of gnome-panel, this will work too.

Answer (score 0):

I use a applet called Jupiter which was originally designed for the eee netbook but should work with any laptop/netbook you can get the deb from their site

- [Jupiter](http://www.jupiterapplet.org/)

or you can add the ppa to get updates - [What are ppa's and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

open a terminal and type

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter`

then this

`sudo apt-get update`

and finally this

`sudo apt-get install jupiter`

one of the functions is to selectively disable either the internal or external displays meaning when you have the big monitor attached you can disable the netbook display having your panels on that screen.

Hope this helps